# How to insert data into a 2D array of objects from a csv file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to insert data into a 2D array of objects from a csv file but I have problems with initializing the 2D array of objects, and I get this error message:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

UPDATE:
I think the problem is with Initializing the array of object , because I tried to insert data manually without using CSV file like this code below and still having the same error message :

UPDATE No.2 :
I tried  to Simplify the code by making 1 object only but still cant insert data

Simplified code :

```
public CoreManager mng = new CoreManager();

void Start()
{
   
    mng.actual_words[1] = "n";    //-> the problem I'm facing is on this line 
    Debug.Log(mng.actual_words[1]);
}
```

Here is my code trying to insert data from csv file :

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    int sentenceNumber = 0;
    int storynumber = 0;

    public CoreManager[][] mng = new CoreManager[5][];

    void Start()
    {
        TextAsset questdata = Resources.Load<TextAsset>    ("first_storytest");
        string[] data = questdata.text.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
        Debug.Log(data.Length);
        for (int i = 1; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            string[] row = data[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            for(int x = 0; x < row.Length; x++)
            {
                if (row[x] != "")
                {
                    if (row[x] == "***")
                    {
                        storynumber++;
                        sentenceNumber = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mng[storynumber][sentenceNumber].actual_words[x] = row[x];
                    }
                }
            }
            sentenceNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code trying to insert one item manually :

```
int sentenceNumber = 0;
int storynumber = 0; 
public CoreManager[][] mng = new CoreManager[5][];
void Start()
 {
   mng[storynumber][sentenceNumber].actual_words[1]="test1";

 }
```

---

```
public class CoreManager
{
    [Tooltip("Write these words in actual sequence of the sentence")]
    public string[] actual_words;

    [Tooltip("Write these words in any sequence of the sentence")]
    public string[] mixed_words;
}
```

Comment: new CoreManager[5][]  -- means that you can have Max 5 rows of data. Thats where you get Indies out of bounds.

Comment: Can we have a peek at the csv file?

Comment: the csv file have only 2 rows (storynumber)>>>> the file is in arabic i dont think it can be shown here 



the (actual_words;) from the (CoreManager)  is array so mng is an 2Darray of objects and each object is an array

Answer (score 0):

This line of code only allows 5 entries in one dimension but doesn't allocate any space for the other direction. If you're using arrays, you need to provide the size up front.

```
public CoreManager[][] mng = new CoreManager[5][];
```

For testing purposes, I'd set the mng to [100][100] and use a small csv and see if this fixes your problem. If it does, then that's definitely the problem. If it doesn't, then something else is wrong.

Edit: After reviewing this some more, I'd suggest changing your data structure to use [Dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) instead. This will provide more flexibility at runtime.

2nd Edit:
Or you can go with a [multidemensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) which has a different syntax.

[Feel free to run this example for yourself](https://ideone.com/2NlDdI):

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Lets get started!");
        int[,] mng = new int[5,5];
        
        mng[0,0] = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(mng[0,0]);
    }

// Output:
// Lets get started!
// 5
```

Comment: i think the problem is with Initializing  the array of object , becouse i tried to  insert data manually  without using CSV file like this code below and still having the same error message  :

int sentenceNumber = 0;
    int storynumber = 0;

    public CoreManager[][] mng = new CoreManager[5][];

    void Start()
    {
              mng[storynumber][sentenceNumber].actual_words[1]="test1";
    }

Comment: thanks for the advice i will have a look at the  Dictionaries data structure i actually  never worked with it before i will give it a try and let you know

Comment: Instead of using the array of arrays, try using multidemensional array. See my updated answer.

Comment: I did unfortunately it didn't work still having the same error message

Comment: You have a 2D array of objects that also have arrays. Each of these needs to be initialized like you said above.

Comment: that is exactly my problem ...... i worked on it yesterday now i can initialize  and insert data into the array but somehow i cant access the data ... i will write a new Question explaining the new problem and thin i will write the answer in this one